# Simple loop that Add lines in .txt file - Powershell

Tags: loops, powershell, for-loop, process

I am creating a script in PS that will add process info into a .log file in every 3 minutes in 1 hour. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
$w3wpproc =  Get-Process -Name w3wp | ft -View process 
$ieproc =  Get-Process -Name iexplore | ft -View process
$data = Get-Date 

For($data; $data.ToShortTimeString() -le "15:00"; $data.AddMinutes("3"))
{
$w3wpproc | Out-File "c:\logs_proces\iis_worker.log" -Append | Add-Content "c:\logs_proces\iis_worker.log `n" 
$ieproc | Out-File "c:\logs_proces\iexplorer.log" -Append | Add-Content "c:\logs_proces\iexplorer.log `n"  
}
```

Comment: Using `-Append` You wouldn't need the `Add-Content` part

Comment: Ok, thanks for information. Anyway it doesn't resolve the problem I have. In this script i want to add something like "time stamp". I've tryed this:
For($data; $data.ToShortTimeString() -le "15:00"; $data.AddMinutes("10"))
{

$data.DateTime | Out-File "c:\logs_proces\iis_worker.log" -Append

$w3wpproc | Out-File "c:\logs_proces\iis_worker.log" -Append 
$ieproc | Out-File "c:\logs_proces\iexplorer.log" -Append 
}
but the time is always the same. Anyway this script i have Add process info in every 0,05second or something like that. I dont get it.

Comment: To get the current time you can use `$data.TimeOfDay` That will return a string with the current time, from here you can access the hours, mins and secs

Comment: Ok, I have the time stamp. 
I used function when i declare Get-Time and its ok. How can i send process info at every 3 minutes, not at 0,05s?

Comment: You want it to RUN every 3 minutes or record a large amount of time data in 3 minute intervals?

Comment: I have got the solution i think. I need only to know that my FOR loop is ok?  
I used in my For loop command Start-Sleep -Seconds 180 and it works, but i don't know when my loop is going to stop. Could u explain me this? Im newbie in powershell so this "-le" stamp its not similiar to me.

Comment: Good as an excercise but if you are using this to solve a real world problem you are having, there are better tools available. Out of the box you have Performance Counters and Etw. Sysinternals has Procmon or it's lightversion SysMon. No doubt many other solutions exist.

Comment: Yes, it's just for excercise :). I think we can close this thread. Thank U all for help.

Comment: Here is a good example on how to use a timeout, you can set the `-minutes` tag for 3 minutes here https://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/making-a-timed-loop-in-powershell/

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using a scheduled task?